# WPF RichTextBox automatically merges two adjacent Runs

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument, text-formatting, inlines

I have a `RichTextBox` containing two `Runs`:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument>
            <FlowDocument.Blocks>
                <Paragraph Name="par">
                    <Run Text="First"/>
                    <Run Text="Second"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument.Blocks>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox.Document>
</RichTextBox>
```

When I iterate through the `Inlines` of the `par`, I see three `Runs`: "First", " "(space) and "Second". It's ok. But if I delete second " " `Run` (using Backspace key, for example) and then iterate through the `Inlines` of the `par`, I see only one "FirstSecond" `Run`. `RichTextBox` merges two remaining `Runs` into single `Run`. However, if "First" and "Second" `Runs` have different `TextFont` or `TextWeight` values, `RichTextBox` won't merge them and I'll see two distinct `Runs`: "First" and "Second".

Now my question: How can I preserve adjacent `Runs` from being merged automatically by `RichTextBox`?

I would like to get the behaviour similar to the one when `Runs` have different `TextFont` or `TextWeight` values, but visually their formats should be equal. I've tried to set different `Tag` values for the different `Runs`, but it didn't help. Maybe, there is some "logical" format, that doesn't influence the appearance of the `Runs`, but warns RichTextBox to distinguish them.

Answer (score 3):

Though I haven't found a clear solution, there is a workaround. `Run` has the `Typography` property, which, in its turn, has the `Int32` [`AnnotationAlternates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.Documents.Typography.AnnotationAlternates%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) property. This property defines the fine tuning of the outlook for the specific characters of the specific fonts. If this property isn't used as intended, it can be used as a "logical" format for a `Run`. As written in MSDN:

> If the value of AnnotationAlternates is greater than zero and the
>   selected font does not support annotation alternates, the default form
>   of the letter is displayed.

In my application I use `Segoe UI` font, which, as it turns out, doesn't support annotation alternates, so this workaround works for me. If you use font that supports annotation alternates, you can try to use rather big values of the `AnnotationAlternates` property, maybe, it won't influence the appearance of the text.

Comment: I used AnnotationAltenatives to overcome this. However when it came to handling multiple langauages, it was a barrier. Other alternative was to use StylisticAlternatives.

Comment: The other alternative to above way is to handle key events and remove text, either entire selected or one by one. This is very tedious to handle many scenarios, but works.